# Rules for using possessive "s" to describe quantity

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives, apostrophe

I'd like to know how to explain the rules for use of *possessive "s"* to describe the quantity of something, as in, "*two hours' work*" to an English learner.

[This answer at english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/should-two-weeks-vacation-be-written-two-weeks-vacation-with-a-possessive-a), suggests the phrase "...worth of..." is omitted. I don't think anything's necessarily omitted, so it's more precise to say that "worth of" can be added between the "'s" and the noun without changing the meaning.

This sentence is grammatical and idiomatic:

> *People need **between seven and nine hours’ sleep** every day.*

But these feel somewhere between unnatural and nonsense even though they work fine with "worth of" inserted:

> *There's **5 million dollars' jewellery** behind that glass.*
>
> *I drove through **three thousand kilometres' desert** in the last couple days.*
>
> *I bought **a salary's farmland** to retire on.*

From these, I'm guessing that this possessive "s" structure can only be used naturally with units of time.

My questions: 
***Can the possessive "s" with this function reliably be replaced with "worth of"? 

Does this structure work only with units of time? 

Does this structure work reliably with any noun measured by units of time? 

What's the name of this structure's function for easier Googling?***

Comment: *I have 8 hours’ sleep every night = I have 8 hours **of sleep** every night = I have **a sleep of** 8 hours every night*. The sleep doesn't "possess" the timespan, any more than the timespan possesses the sleep. Also note that there are quite a few separate written instances of [***between seven and nine hours sleep***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22between+seven+and+nine+hours%E2%80%99+sleep%22) in Google Books, but I don't see ***any*** with an apostrophe (as opposed to, say, [***a full day's work***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+full+day%27s+work%22)).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ngrams currently puts the apostrophe ahead of no apostrophe, but the issue is certainly not settled.

Comment: You can't search NGrams for a sequence of more than 5 words, and in any case there wouldn't be enough instances of "between [number] and [number] hours sleep" to work with. Having said that, I've just compared the 4-word sequence [***need eight hours' sleep***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=need+eight+hours+sleep%2Cneed+eight+hours%27+sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) with and without apostrophe, and you're right that the apostrophe seems to be more common. I think that's some kind of artefact - I can't find ***any*** actual examples when I drill down.

Comment: I'm particularly taken by the first result returned by [this Google Books search:](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+do+eight+hours+work+for+eight%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJobRzwqQ9umBC9XV-SgqGMDThbcA%3A1631447652687&ei=ZOo9YfGkKcf5gQbDq4jQBA&oq=%22to+do+eight+hours+work+for+eight%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...11614.12231.0.12612.3.3.0.0.0.0.78.213.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.9RlROyBqEKg) *I secured two amendments to the House bill city of Washington to do **eight hours work** for **eight hours' pay**, which changed this system of taxation.*

Comment: ...note that there are two other results for the above search that show the full text, and neither of them have ***any*** apostrophes. Lord knows what the US politician (or his stenographer) thought they were doing only putting an apostrophe before ***pay***, but not ***work***. Whatever - so far as I'm concerned, that's the only relevant apostrophe I've found so far, and it was clearly written by someone who hasn't got a clue how to write properly!

Comment: Check out this NGram for the three sequences [*in two **days** time, in two **days'** time, in two **day's** time*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+two+days+time%2Cin+two+days%27+time%2Cin+two+day%27s+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20days%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20days%20%27%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20day%20%27s%20time%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20days%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20days%20'%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20two%20day%20's%20time%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: According to that chart, over 80% of all matches include an apostrophe. But I don't believe this is remotely true, and I can't actually find any instances of the apostrophe when I drill down into the results themselves. Obviously NGrams simply isn't reliable when it comes to punctuation marks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Odd how NGrams seems unable to distinguish between apostrophe and no apostrophe, yet  presents a clear difference on the chart, rather than representing them as the same.

Comment: I find it odd that most/all writers agree with me that there's no apostrophe in a context like *We did **eight hours work** today*, but everyone agrees we need one in *We observed **one minute's silence** today*. The fact that there's such universal agreement (that there's a ***difference***) strongly implies to me that there must be some clearly-defined principle governing our orthographic choice here. But I can't imagine what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuitions are correct that only the temporal measures can be possessive without "worth". [CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) p. 470 calls these **measure genitives**:

> [46] [**an hour's** delay], [**one week's** holiday], this [**hour's** delay], a second [**one hour's** delay], the [**one dollar's** worth of chocolates] he bought
>
> Genitives of this kind measure just temporal length or value: we do not have, for example, **They had [**a mile's** walk]* (spatial distance) or **We bought [**a pound's** carrots]* (weight). Value measures take the noun *worth* as head, while the temporal ones allow any semantically appropriate noun as head. An alternative means of expressing measure is to use a compound adjective, as in *a [**two-hour** delay]*, *a [**five-mile** walk]*, *an [**eight-pound** baby]*, etc.; this is less restricted than the genitive, though it is not admissible with *worth*.